# How to manage concatination with javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sent value as 'English' word to function. 
This is JavaScript code -

```
return "<div  >  <a href='javascript:void(0);'  onclick='audio_change()' >English </a>   </div>";
```

like this - `onclick="audio_change('English')"` . But how single, double quotes manage during add 'English' in function's brackets.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the quotes inside quotes using `\`.

```
return "<div><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='audio_change()' onclick='audio_change(\'English\')' >English</a></div>";


return "<div><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='audio_change()' onclick=\"audio_change('English')\" >English</a></div>";
```

When adding `'` inside single-quoted string or `"` inside double-quoted string you should escape the quote.
Or you can also use single quotes inside double quotes and vice-versa

```
'He said \'Hello\''

"He said \"Hello\""

'He said "Hello"'

"He said 'Hello'"
```

Comment: And how to add second parameter in same function audio_change() ?       I want to add like -  audio_change('English', document.getElementById('textvalue').value)

Comment: `return "<div><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='audio_change()' onclick='audio_change(\'English\')' onchange='audio_change(\'English\', document.getElementById(\'textvalue\').value)'>English</a></div>";`

Comment: The second param will be string, not the value of `textvalue`

Comment: But I want to get text box value as a second parameter.

Comment: return "<div><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='audio_change()' onclick='audio_change(\'English\')' onchange='audio_change(\'English\', \'" + document.getElementById('textvalue').value + "\'')>English</a></div>";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78192/discussion-between-ketan-patil-and-tushar).

Answer (score 0):

Use escape `char` "\" as,

```
return "<div><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"audio_change('English')\" >English</a></div>";
```